# SQL Azure Project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure-sql-database

For the past couple of weeks I've been getting an annoying error in Visual Studio 2010 when I open up a solution.

I created SQL Azure Database project a while back and suddenly it isn't working on all but 1 one of my machines.

I get the following error and the project does not load:

**Failed to create extension manager with database schema provider 'Microsoft.Data.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureDatabaseSchemaProvider'**

I cannot find any information on the class mentioned in the error and I have searched for it on the machine on which the project loads and I cannot find anything.

Any ideas on this one?  It's driving me a little nuts.

Thanks all.

-SM

Comment: of interest?: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/291bfe86-9baa-4786-8290-339326cc09b1/

Answer (score 0):

Hummm.... I never ran into this issue, but can you verify that your connection string points to the user database, not master?